# Expect script return value

Tags: bash, authentication, ssh, expect

I'm including simple Expect commands within a Bash script (I know I could be just writing a pure Expect script, but I would like to get it to work from within Bash).

The script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=$(expect -c '
spawn ssh mihail911@blah.org
expect "password:"
send "dog\r"
')
```

Upon ssh'ing to the above address, it will return something of the form `mihail911's password:` on the prompt, so I think my expect line is valid.

When I run this my script does not print anything. It does not even show the `password:` prompt. In general, even if I manually provide an incorrect password, I will receive a `Incorrect password`-type response prompt. Why is nothing printing and how can I get my script to execute properly?

I have tried debugging by using the `-d` flag and it seems to show that at least the first expect prompt is being matched properly.

In addition, what values should I expect in the `OUTPUT` variable? When I `echo` this variable, it simply prints the first the first command of the expect portion of the script and then `mihail911's password:`. Is this what it's supposed to be printing?

Comment: Share `Expect`'s debug output info which you have observed after enabling `exp_internal 1`

Comment: If you don't particularly want to capture the output from Expect (and prevent it from being immediately printed), then don't.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(expect -c '
    # To suppress any other form of output generated by spawned process
    log_user 0
    spawn ssh dinesh@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    # To match some common prompts. Update it as per your needs.
    # To match literal dollar, it is escaped with backslash
    set prompt "#|>|\\$"
    expect {
        eof     {puts "Connection rejected by the host"; exit 0}
        timeout {puts "Unable to access the host"; exit 0;}
        "password:"
    }
    send "root\r"
    expect {
        timeout {puts "Unable to access the host"; exit 0;}
        -re $prompt
    }
    send "date\r"
    # Matching only the date cmd output alone
    expect {
        timeout { puts "Unable to access the host";exit 0}
        -re "\n(\[^\r]*)\r"
    }
    send_user "$expect_out(1,string)\n"
    exit 1
')
echo "Expect's return value: $?"; # Printing value returned from 'Expect'
echo "Expect Output: $OUTPUT"
```

**Output:**

```
dinesh@MyPC:~/stackoverflow$ ./Meric
Expect's return value: 1
Expect Output: Wed Sep  2 09:35:14 IST 2015
dinesh@MyPC:~/stackoverflow$
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can use `expect_before {timeout {puts "..."}}` so you don't have to have the timeout clause in every expect command.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow the script. What is each line responsible for? What is captured by $OUTPUT vs. $?? What does the 'eof' line do?