# Expect script: to perform actions after closing ssh

Tags: bash, expect

The question is to preserve a variable and to perform actions after closing ssh within expect script inside bash.

This is what I`ve got so far:

```
echo "Getting package name..."

getPackageName=$(expect -c '
exp_internal 1
log_user 1
global expect_out

# puts "Getting package name..."

spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o RSAAuthentication=no -l user 10.20.30.40
sleep 1

expect {
    "*sword*" {
        send "12341234\r"
    }
    timeout {
        send_user "Error: timeout\n"
        exit 1
    }
}

expect {
    "*user@*>*" {
        # getting name of the latest modified file
        send "cd /export/home/user/Releases/build/1.3.32.0 && find * -type f -printf '"'"'%T@ %p\\n'"'"' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d\" \"\r"
    }
    timeout {
        send_user "Error: timeout\n"
        exit 1
    }
}

expect {
    "BUILD_MAIN*" {
        # assigning value to variable
        set result_lines [split $expect_out(0,string) \r\n]
        set package_filename [lindex $result_lines 0]
        puts "package_filename: $package_filename"
    }
    timeout {
        send_user "Error: timeout\n"
        exit 1
    }
}

expect "*#"
send "exit\r"

# here I need to perform some actions on local machine after ssh logout
expect "Connection*"
send "export LATEST_BUILD=$package_filename\r"
send_user "Message sent to user"

')
```

So, in the bottom block I am trying to set environment variable (LATEST_BUILD) on the local machine after closing ssh, and also to paste there a value of variable (package_filename) which has been defined earlier during ssh session.

The point here is that I see the last "Message sent to user" in the output, but the previous send "export LATEST_BUILD=12345\r" obviously does not work.

Comment: Once the ssh closed, the `send "export LATEST_BUILD=$package_filename\r"` will be failed to reach as you might have got the `spawn_id not open` error message. You should have spawned the `bash` shell instead. Note that the exported variable will only be available till the session closed by `Expect`.

Comment: I'm no bash expert. (Others can comment). I don't know why you are not getting the `stderr` output for the command substitution due to `expect`'s error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. Can you perhaps provide a correct example of code? I have been playing with "exit\r" to ssh and then "spawn bash -i" (and some other spawn bash args), but my "send" still does nothing on local machine. Is it enough to send "exit\r" or I need smth else? The whole thing is to return some value to environment variable on local machine. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @nonrandom_passer , if it's the end-result that you're looking at, there's one other way. Since you already know the credentials and path of the target system, you can create the file on the remote machine and scp it backwards. And about the code you've pasted, could you check if it helps if - you expected for a prompt ("$") rather than a console message ("Connection*") ?

Comment: Hi @alok , you're right, also there are more ways to perform it on remote machine, but I want to cope with it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

getPackageName=$(expect -c '

# A common prompt matcher
set prompt "%|>|#|\\\$ $"

# To suppress any other form of output generated by spawned process
log_user 0   

### Spawning ssh here ###
spawn ssh user@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
expect "password"
send "welcome!2E\r"
expect -re $prompt  

# Your further code 

send "exit\r"
expect eof

##### The below segment is not needed ######
##### if your intention is to get only the 'package_filename' value #####
#    spawn bash
#    expect -re $prompt
#    send "export LATEST_BUILD=54.030\r"
#    expect -re $prompt
#    send "echo \$LATEST_BUILD\r"
#    expect -re $prompt
#    send "exit\r"
#    expect eof
#
##### The End ######


# Enabling logging now ...  
log_user 1
# Print only the value which you want to return
puts "$package_filename"
')

echo $getPackageName
```

`eof` is used to identify the end-of-file event i.e. closure of connection.

Note : The exported variable `LATEST_BUILD` only be available for the spawned bash session.

**Update :**

`log_user`  is used to turn off/on the logging generated by `Expect` at any time.

```
log_user 0; # Turn off logging
log_user 1; # Turn on logging
```

I hope that your only intention is to get the `package_filename`. So, we don't even need to spawn bash shell. Instead, simply print the value at last, thereby making it to be available to the parent bash script.

Comment: To make the code more robust, you can define the exit status for your code based on timeout events and pass conditions.  Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32344647/974155) to know about the same which does the similar kind of job.

Comment: thanks a ton. Really missed eof. There is no way to make the exported variable available for bash session of parent script?

Comment: You mean you want the value of the `package_filename` to be available to the main bash script ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I've been trying to do.

Comment: Do you have any ideas if this is doable?

Comment: @nonrandom_passer : I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This was my first decision, but then with the purpose of displaying and debugging I thought to use environment variable on the local machine because such way you don't need to hide output. So, is "log_user 0" the only way to return value (without touching remote machine)? What to do if expect script is bigger and serves several purposes?

Comment: Don't want to put here long comments, just need to know if any other option exists. Haven't found yet while googling.

Comment: To my knowledge, as of now, I also don't know how to return multiple values, rather than returning them like any delimiter (i.e. comma or space) separated values which will further parsed in the parent bash script again. May any other experts reading this, can help us.

Comment: Currently came to a decision to partly use "log_user 0", then to turn it on and then to parse output.