# How do I get the result of a command from a remote server using ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, filenames

I am working in Linux bash (version 16.04.4 LTS).
I am using ssh to connect to a remote server where I want to find for a specific file from a list of files (most recent file version) and then retrieve only the version.
For example, considering this files on the remote server (server.com):

```
file-30.0-2.tar.xz
file-30.0-3.tar.xz
file-30.0-4.tar.xz
file-30.0-5.tar.xz
file-30.0-7.tar.xz
file-30.0-10.tar.xz
```

If I login directly in the remote server and If I try the following command it works.

```
ls file-*.tar.xz | sort -V | tail -n1 | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+'
```

Output: `30.0-10`

As I am working from another server I am using ssh to connect to remote server like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail

ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey user@server.com "cd /myDir; \\
  ls file-*.tar.xz | sort -V | tail -n1 | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+')"
```

This command it's working and I get the same output as before (30.0-10).

But I want to be able to pass that result (30.0-10) to outside the script and use it in the local server.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's almost always going to be easier to put your command in a single script, copy that to the remote server, then execute the script. Putting arbitrary shell pipelines in a single argument to `ssh` invites quoting problems.

Comment: I could do that but given that I only want to run 2 commands couldn´t it be done like this?

Comment: Use a heredoc to feed the command to stdin of ssh instead of trying to specify as args on the CLI.

Comment: how? can you please explain?

Comment: Use `expect` to login to remote servers and list the directories.  You can return this output to your shell script and process further.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341234/expect-script-return-value

Comment: Beside the point, but that version number isn't for Bash or Linux. It looks like it's for Ubuntu (Xenial release).

Comment: I edited the title to clarify it for you. See [ask] for tips on writing a good title in the future.

Comment: You can always use command substition (`$(...)`). It works with `ssh` exactly the same way as it works with any other command.

Comment: Your earlier, now-deleted question had the code in a here document, and it was failing for other reasons. Perhaps your question should mention that, even though you apparently never managed to debug it.

Comment: I changed the code but the issue looks the same... The problem is that ls command as a lot o pipes and it is not being read as one command by the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign the output of your script to a variable and later use that variable:

```
result="$(./yourscript)"
echo "Result from SSH = $result"
```

Comment: I did the pipe inside a script, and then I tried your approach. when I run the script I get 30.0-10. Than when I echo the VAR I get "echo".

Comment: @Fr0zt how do you echo the var?

Comment: highest_version="$(./script.sh)"  -- this is working as the highest version is being shown.
echo "$highest_version"   - I get "echo"

Comment: @Fr0zt that can't be right. Running `./script.sh` gives the correct output? What does `printf '%s\n' "$highest_ersion"` give?

Comment: This worked. I had a unknown bug in my code which was making me think that I had and error. But this approach worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Print null delimited file list remotely, sort it by reverse major version, and patch version, so the latest is listed first

```bash
read -r -d '' latest_archive < <(
  ssh \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey \
    user@server.com \
    printf '%s\\0' '/my/dir/file-*[[:digit:]].tar.xz' | sort -zt- -k2nr,3nr
)
```

How it works:

- `printf '%s\\0' '/my/dir/file-*[[:digit:]].tar.xz'`: Prints null-delimited list of files matching the pattern.
- `| sort -zt- -k2nr,3nr`: Pipe to sort `-z` null-delimited entries, `-t-` with dash `-` as field delimiter, `-k2nr,3nr` on 2nd field numerically, largest first, combined with 3rd field numerically and also largest first.

Comment: The remote server is Ubuntu, so it will have `sort -z`; but perhaps mention that this is not portable to non-Linux platforms etc.

Comment: Also, the `sort` arguments presuppose that none of the parent directories contain a dash in their name.

Comment: printf '%s\\0' 'file-*[[:digit:]].tar.xz' is not printing anything

Comment: @Fr0zt then you are not running sh or bash but zsh or some non posix shell variant